# Missing reference to a LINQ class

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to work through the ObjectDataSource example in the free tutorial by Dan Wahlin (PluralSight)

```
http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-03&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro
```

I add a LINQ to SQL class (dbml file).

This creates a class: NorthwindDataContext, in the namespace: ObjectDataSourceDemo.App_Code.Data.

Now I create another class (BizRules.cs) in the project. The class is created in the "ObjectDataSourceDemo" namespace. When I write some code that calls "new NorthwindDataContext" the IDE shows an error "type or namespace could not be found".

What can I do to fix this? I am confused because it seems like they are all in the same namespace.

Here is the folder structure I am working with:
[image: Folder structure of project]

Comment: If you search your solution for NorthwindDataContext, where do you find it?  What is the namespace for the class?

Comment: It is in the Northwind.designer.cs file. and in the ObjectDataSourceDemo.App_Code.Data namespace (as I said above). If I type:
using ObjectDataSourceDemo.App_Code.Data; 
in the BizRules.cs file, it underlines "App_Code" in red, with error:
The type or namespace name 'App_Code' does not exist in the namespace 'ObjectDataSourceDemo' (ps. I added the App_Code folder manually, there was no special inbuilt command like there is for App_Data for example...)

Comment: If you right-click on NorthwindDataContext in your BizRules.cs class you should see a "Resolve" item in the menu. Select the first item in that menu (the "using" one) and the proper namespace should automatically be added. If that's not showing then there's probably another issue that's causing the problem.

Comment: I could not see such a menu item. I tried again with a new project and placed the dbml and cs files in the root folder and everything worked fine. However, when placing the dbml/cs files in sub folders (e.g. App_Code/Data..) I kept on running into problems. i) Are there any rules to keep in mind when placing code files in subfolders? ii) I was also curious how you got the App_Code folder there (since the VS IDE does not seem to have any action for this) Did you just add it manually? - Thanks